# How can I use awk to remove duplicate entries in the same field with data separated with commas?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to call awk from a bash script to remove duplicate data entries of a field in a file.

Data Example in file1

> data1 a,b,c,d,d,d,c,e

> data2 a,b,b,c

Desired Output:

> data1 a,b,c,d,e

> data2 a,b,c

First I removed the first column to only have the second remaining.

```
cut --complement -d$'\t' -f1 file1 &> file2
```

This worked fine, and now I just have the following in file2:

> a,b,c,d,d,d,c,e

> a,b,b,c

So then I tried this code that I found but do not understand well:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            printf "%s", (!seen[$1]++? (i==1?"":FS) $i: "" )
    delete seen; print ""
}' file2
```

The problem is that this code was for a space delimiter and mine is now a comma delimiter with variable values on each row. This code just prints the file as is and I can see no difference. I also tried to make the FS a comma by doing this, to no avail:

```
printf "%s", (!seen[$1]++? (i==1?"":FS=",") $i: ""
```

Comment: do you care about order? eg. `data1 e,d,c,b,a` ?

Comment: you have mistyped the code you found. should be `$i` not `$1`.

Comment: I do not care about order. I could probably just sort later. I also just corrected the typo you mentioned and I still do not see the duplicates removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the code you found.

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '
    {
        s = $1 " " $2
        seen[$2]++

        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
            if (!seen[$i]++) s = s "," $i

        print s
        delete seen
    }
' data-file
```

- `-F'[ ,]'` - split input lines on spaces and commas
- `s = ...` - we could use `printf` like the code you found, but building a string is less typing
- `!seen[x]++` is a common idiom - it returns true only the first time `x` is seen
- to avoid special-casing when to print a comma (as your sample code does with spaces), we simply add `$2` to the print string and set `seen[$2]`
- then for the remaining columns (3 .. NF), we add comma and column if it hasn't been seen before
- `delete seen` - clear the array for the next line

Comment: This works best. I didn't know you could define two delimiters, so that simplifies things. Can you explain the `s = s "," $i` ? Also, this added a new problem which is that there are no commas after the first $2 entry, but I quickly fixed that with `sed ' s/ /,/g' file`. I think I can fix the same problem by making that first line in the curly brackets `s = $1 " " $2,`.

Comment: @quantumDog [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) -- worth it's weight in gold.

Comment: I fixed that there are no commas after first entry by making the first line in the curly brackets `s = $1 "," $2`. Also, now there is no way to compare the first entry in the second column, so I have duplicates of it in certain places.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I'm just now discovering this. I didn't even know awk was a whole language until a week ago.

Comment: `awk` is the Swiss-Army knife of text processing. Every minute learning it, is time well spent. It works surprisingly similar to C (from a syntax standpoint). It's not that bad once you understand `awk` processes each record (line)  of input by applying each `"optional pattern" { ... rule ... }` in the order you write them. There is a special `BEGIN {}` rule (that is run before the 1st record is read) and an `END {}` rule, run after the last record is procesed. There are a number of special variables, `FS`, `OFS`, `RS`, `ORS`, `NR`, `FNR`, etc..  Great tool.

Comment: So I substituted `if (!seen[$i]++) s = s "," $i` with `if (!seen[$i]++ &&$3!=$1) s = s "," $i`, but it still doesn't catch the duplicates of the first entry. So **data3 a,b,c,a** exists because I can't compare the first a.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have not been exposed to ORS or NR yet, other than hearing folks say it is the reason why print "" is better that printf /n or some such.

Comment: my code was written to manipulate your original data (`data1 a,b,c,d,d,d,c,e`) to produce your "desired output" directly. It isn't supposed to read the output from your cut command. For input `data3 a,b,c,a` it outputs `data3 a,b,c`. If you're getting something different, perhaps you have changed the code somewhere.

Comment: Re `s = s "," $i`: `$` is a unary prefix operator that expects to be followed by something that turns into a number. It then returns the value of that field. awk concatentates strings by simply writing them. So here, `s` is assigned the old value of `s` concatenated with a comma and the value of the ith field.

Answer (score 1):

That code is right, you need to specify the delimiter and change $1 to $i.

```
$ awk -F ',' '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            printf "%s", (!seen[$i]++? (i==1?"":FS) $i: "" )
    delete seen; print ""
}' /tmp/file1
data1 a,b,c,d,e
data2 a,b,c
```

Comment: this code breaks on some input. eg: `data3 a,a,b,b,c`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Now I'm going to try and use sed to find instances of more than 1 comma and replace them with one comma. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` if applicable

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/((\<[^,]*\>).*),\2/\1/;ta' input_file
data1 a,b,c,d,e
data2 a,b,c
```

Comment: this breaks on some input. eg. `b a,b,c`

Answer (score 0):

so i did something similar lately - sanitizing the output of `gnu` prime `factor`ing program when it prints out every single copy of a bunch of small primes :

```
 gawk -Mbe '
 BEGIN {
     __+=__+=__+=(__+=___=_+=__=____=_^=_<_)-+-++_
     __+=__^=!(___=__-=_+=_++)
     for (_; _<=___; _+=__) {
         if ((_%++__)*(_%(__+--__))) {
             print ____*=_^_
         }
      }
  } | gfactor  | sanitize_gnu_factor

58870952193946852435332666506835273111444209706677713:
    7^7
    11^11
    13^13
    17^17
    
116471448967943114621777995869564336419122830800496825559417754612566153180027:
    7^7
    11^11
    13^13
    17^17
    19^19
    
2431978363071055324951111475877083878108827552605151765803537946846931963403343871776360412541253748541645309:
    7^7
    11^11
    13^13
    17^17
    19^19
    23^23
    
6244557167645217304114386952069758950402417741892127946837837979333340639740318438767128131418285303492993082345658543853142417309747238004933649896921:
    7^7
    11^11
    13^13
    17^17
    19^19
    23^23
    29^29
    
823543:
    7^7
    
234966429149994773:
    7^7
    11^11
    
71165482274405729335192792293569:
    7^7
    11^11
    13^13
```

And the core sanitizer does basically the same thing - intra-row duplicate removal :

```
sanitize_gnu_factor()          # i implemented it as a shell function
{
    mawk -Wi -- '
    BEGIN {
        ______ = "[ ]+"
        ___= _+= _^=__*=____ = FS
       _______ = FS = "[ \v"(OFS = "\f\r\t")"]+"
            FS = ____
    } {
       if (/ is prime$/) {
          print; next
       } else if (___==NF) {
          $NF = " - - - - - - - \140\140\140"\
                "PRIME\140\140\140 - - - - - - - "
       } else {
            split("",_____)
                _ = NF
            do { _____[$_]++ } while(--_<(_*_))
                delete _____[""]
            sub("$"," ")
            _^=_<_
            for (__ in _____) {
                 if (+_<+(___=_____[__])) {
                    sub(" "(__)"( "(__)")+ ",
                    sprintf(" %\47.f^%\47.f ",__,___))
            } }
              ___ = _+=_^=__*=_<_
            FS = _______
         $__ = $__
        FS = ____ } } NF = NF' |

    mawk -Wi -- '
        / is prime$/ { print
       next } /[=]/ { gsub("="," ")
                   } $(_^=(_<_)) = \
        (___=length(__=$_))<(_+=_++)^(_+--_) \
              ?__: sprintf("%.*s......%s } %\47.f dgts ",
        _^=++_,__, substr(__,++___-_),--___)' FS='[:]' OFS=':'
}
```